# Using a D-Vine for Cost-Schedule Risk

Tags: copula

I'm new to the Vine Copula world having spent some time with bivariate models, but I'd like to combine pair copula models using a D-Vine.  I understand the concept; I'm just not sure it could work for what I plan.

A project has a schedule and a budget.  At the start there is a Planned finish date and a Planned (expected) final cost.  At the project end, there is an Actual finish date and an Actual (final) cost.  Could these four variables be combined in a 4-d D-Vine copula?  I know they work in bivariates, but I'm not sure how the planned variables would combine conditionally in the tree structure.

Also, there is the issue of dealing with dates (duration) and costs that need to be considered.  All the examples I have seen are purely financial quantities.